# C# COM => pointer => delphi interface

Tags: c#, delphi, delphi-xe2, com-interop

Couple of days I cant make solution to solve my problem. I have interface and class in C# which visible as COM server. And I have Delphi application where I need to access this interface. But in my case I need in C# side to return 32 bit pointer to interface and at Delphi side - to convert pointer to interface. What is done?
c# side. All attributes written well, source code is cutted because original class is much bigger, but idea is understandable:

```
[ComVisible(true)]
[CLSCompliant(true)]
[Guid("C1A57BD0-AAA2-4AB8-BA2F-ADFA04275AD5")]
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None),
 ComSourceInterfaces(typeof(IProcPreviewEndArgs))]
public class ProcPreviewEndArgs : IProcPreviewEndArgs
{

   [ComVisible(true), PreserveSig]
   public IntPtr CreateNew()
   {
       var obj = new ProcPreviewEndArgs();
       GC.SuppressFinalize(obj);
       return Marshal.GetComInterfaceForObject(obj, typeof (IProcPreviewEndArgs));
   }
}
```

delphi side:

```
type
  PIProcPreviewEndArgs = ^IProcPreviewEndArgs;

 Index, Res: Integer;
 ppa : IProcPreviewEndArgs;
 pppa : PIProcPreviewEndArgs;

  ppa := CoProcPreviewEndArgs.Create;   // Creates COM object via Delphi services
  ppa.CreateNew(Res);                   // Creates object of the same type, returns as Ret (Integer)
  pppa := PIProcPreviewEndArgs(Res);    // Trying to cast Intereger to interface
  pppa^.CreateNew(Res); // just to test calling posibility
```

On pppa^ (getting instance by pointer) ACCESS VIOLATION exception is thrown. pointer Res is not null. It is about 60 000 000. Basicly it is kernel space area.

**UPD**

```
[CLSCompliant(true), ComVisible(true),
 InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown),
 Guid("10572D64-B612-468F-86B3-D12F0B6E3CD2")]
public interface IProcPreviewEndArgs
{
    IntPtr CreateNew();
    IntPtr Get(int aMin, int aMax, uint cMin, uint cMax);
    void ToAngle(int x, int y, int w, int h, out int nx, out int ny, out int nw, out int nh);
    IntPtr GetImage();
}
```

Delphi (generated by Delphi and working well when using standard Delphi methods to manipulate COM objects):

```
 IProcPreviewEndArgs = interface(IUnknown)
    ['{10572D64-B612-468F-86B3-D12F0B6E3CD2}']
    function CreateNew(out pRetVal: Integer): HResult; stdcall;
    function Get(aMin: Integer; aMax: Integer; cMin: LongWord; cMax: LongWord; out pRetVal: Integer): HResult; stdcall;
    function ToAngle(x: Integer; y: Integer; w: Integer; h: Integer; out nx: Integer; 
                     out ny: Integer; out nw: Integer; out nh: Integer): HResult; stdcall;
    function GetImage(out pRetVal: Integer): HResult; stdcall;
  end;
```

Delphi version: **Delphi XE2**

Comment: You aren't showing enough code. What is `IProcPreviewEndArgs`? On both sides. And what is `CoProcPreviewEndArgs`? Did that come from your TLB import?

Comment: What are the types of the variables?

Comment: Excuse me, answered as topic update

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that `CreateNew` returns `IProcPreviewEndArgs` rather than `^IProcPreviewEndArgs`. So your code should read:

```
var
  ppa1, ppa2: IProcPreviewEndArgs;
....
ppa1 := CoProcPreviewEndArgs.Create;   
ppa1.CreateNew(Res);                   
ppa2 := IProcPreviewEndArgs(Res);    
ppa2.CreateNew(Res);
```

If I were you I'd declare those `Integer` return values that map to C# `IntPtr` as `Pointer` in Delphi. That way your code will work if ever you compile a 64 bit version.

I'd also contemplate using `safecall` rather than `stdcall` and so get the compiler to convert any errors from `HRESULT` to Delphi exception.

```
IProcPreviewEndArgs = interface(IUnknown)
  ['{10572D64-B612-468F-86B3-D12F0B6E3CD2}']
  function CreateNew: Pointer; safecall;
  function Get(aMin: Integer; aMax: Integer; cMin: LongWord; cMax: LongWord): Pointer; safecall
  procedure ToAngle(x: Integer; y: Integer; w: Integer; h: Integer; out nx: Integer; 
                    out ny: Integer; out nw: Integer; out nh: Integer); safecall;
  function GetImage: Pointer; safecall;
end;
```

I also wonder why you have to return untyped pointers in, for example, `CreateNew`. Why can't you declare that function to return `IProcPreviewEndArgs` on both sides?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Now it works fine! :) I was confused using Delphi pointers. For future investigations I need to remember that there is no diffenerce between languages in pointers using :) Thank you

Comment: Main reason why pure pointers, but not Interface pointers is using Win32API to transfer pointers from one library to another (dont ask why, just customer desire)

Answer (score 1):

Delphi fully supports COM/ActiveX, regardless of where the pointer is coming from.

Q: What version of Delphi are you using?

SUGGESTION:

1) Create a C# test client to test your ProcPreviewEndArgs.CreateNew() method.  See if it works.

2) Review this article:

- http://delphi.about.com/library/weekly/aa121404a.htm

  Change your Delphi code to use COM/ActiveX classes and GUIDS (as opposed to Delphi pointers).  Make it work the same as the C# test client you got working in Step 1.  Make sure you're doing all the "basics", including calling CoInitialize() somewhere in your Delphi .exe before you start using COM/ActiveX.

3) Please consider if you need COM/ActiveX at all.  Perhaps your design can use PInvoke without COM/ActiveX?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yes, its totally easier to use your way but in my case I need to send pointer via Windows messaging queue (WndProc and so on), where in lParam Im trying to send pointer

Comment: @Alexus I hope you realise that you cannot send pointers across processes. In other words, the recipient of the message cannot live in a different process.